Unable to add types to input with transform functionality
I have the following snippet:
  filterCriteria = input.required({
    transform: (value: string) => value.toLocaleLowerCase(),
    alias: 'listCriteria'
  });

I would like to transform the input with a transform method.
As soon as I add types to the input.required part, it does not compile anymore with the following error message:

TS2322: Type '(value: string) => string' is not assignable to type
'undefined'.

It is reproducible in this Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/signal-inputs-deborahk-rpofup?file=src%2Fsnacks%2Fsnack-list.component.ts
My question is, why does this not work? The background of my question is the fact that my template is not happy with the provided type by filterCriteria.

If you use transform fn with an input, you should add a second generic parameter to required <T, transformT>.
TransformT is the type of the transform function's parameter, T is the return type.
When you specify an input transform, the type of the transform function's parameter determines the types of values that can be set to the input in a template. I think that's why you should add this generic additionally.
In your example:
filterCriteria = input.required<string, string>({
    transform: (value: string) => value.toLocaleLowerCase(),
    alias: 'listCriteria'
  });

